# Speeding up finding index of value in list

Tags: python

Trying to find the bottleneck of one of our scripts.

```
if str(fieldvalue) in uniquevalues:
       i = uniquevalues.index(str(fieldvalue))
```

Would it be cheaper to use `try` / `catch` around the `index()` instead?

Is there an alternative way to make this less expensive?

Comment: It will be helpful to know what data structure we are dealing with. What is `uniquevalues`, a list, a string? Is this executed for many `fieldvalues` with the same `uniquevalues` or only once?

Comment: Are you sure you need to use a list? It's not a good data structure for checking containment. If you're not changing the list much consider creating a dictionary to map all values in the list to their index. Otherwise each time you run this code you do a linear time operation on the list when it can be done in constant time.

Comment: if you're trying to find bottlenecks, have you tried profiling yet?

Comment: "Would it be cheaper to use try / catch around the index() instead?" yes, although it would still be the same algorithmic complexity. Do you really need a list?

Comment: Why do you need to find the index? What will you use it for? If it's to lookup a value in another list you might be better using `zip`, or putting the data together in a `struct` or a `namedtuple`, or using a dictionary with the value as a key, etc, etc

Answer (score 2):

It is not only cheaper, but better (especially for concurrency), to use `try`/`except` in this situation:

```
try:
    i = uniquevalues.index(str(fieldvalue))
except ValueError:
    print('not found')
```

This is the [`EAFP`](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-eafp) principle:

> **EAFP**
>
> Easier to ask for forgiveness than permission. This common Python coding style assumes the existence of valid keys or attributes and catches exceptions if the assumption proves false. This clean and fast style is characterized by the presence of many try and except statements. The technique contrasts with the LBYL style common to many other languages such as C.

Comment: While true, this is hardly the referred to bottleneck as it doesn't change the time complexity.

Comment: @schwobaseggl Still, `index` is better than `in` + `index`.

Answer (score 2):

The alternative is not to use a list. A dictionary `.get` is faster than a list `.index`.

```
uniquevalues_d = {k: i for i, k in enumerate(uniquevalues)}
index = uniquevalues_d.get(str(fieldvalue))  #get returns None if the value is not found
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `set` instead of list. It's hashed and the right object for this purpose.

```
uniquevalues = ['honda','toyota','chevy']
uniqueset = set(uniquevalues)
fieldvalue = 'honda'

if str(fieldvalue) in uniqueset:
       i = uniquevalues.index(str(fieldvalue))

print i
```

This changes if you just care about containment and you don't care about order or position.

```
uniquevalues = {'honda', 'toyota', 'chevy'}
fieldvalue = 'honda'
i = str(fieldvalue) in uniquevalues
print i
```